# Adding background music to a 8086 assembly game

Tags: assembly, masm, tasm, emu8086, dosbox

I'm creating a dosbox game using  assembly 8086 as my programming language. I want to add some background music to the game. I'm using tasm/masm assembler.

How am I supposed to do that and what do I exactly need ?

I'm trying to play midi files while the game is running.

Comment: DOSBox apparently emulates an MPU-401 MIDI card.  There is info about programming those [here](http://midi.teragonaudio.com/tech/mpu.htm).  Note that you'll need a separate hardware or software MIDI synthesizer to actually generate sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOS doesn't have any abstractions for PCM or MIDI sound, so you need to program the hardware directly. How this is done depends on the hardware.

Here's a manual I found online about SoundBlaster cards:
https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/hardware/SoundBlaster.pdf

And here is some information about AdLib cards:
http://shipbrook.net/jeff/sb.html

There are many more resources you can find on Google with search terms such as "AdLib Programming", including YouTube tutorials.

Comment: DOSBOX itself has some useful [docs](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Sound).  Apparently: *DOSBox is able to emulate MIDI in either regular or uart modes.*